# What's wrong with this Flask request?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have been working with flask for a long while, but after a break from it, I cant seem to figure out what's wrong here.

index.html:

```
<input name="linkHolder" type="url" class="defaultTextBox advancedSearchTextBox link" placeholder="http://www.youtube.com">

<form method="POST" action="/button">
    <input class="btn" type="submit">Go</input>
</form>
```

main.py:

```
  @app.route('/button', methods=["GET", "POST"])
  def button():
    if request.method == "POST":
      dlink = request.form.get("linkHolder")
      print(dlink)
      return render_template("index.html", dlink=dlink)
```

I'm sorry if its a simple answer but my end goal here is to load the link typed by the user, print said link, and then reload the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you need to put the input into the form

Comment: How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index.html`, your `<form>` tag does not include the `linkHolder` input.
Do the following:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/button">
    <input name="linkHolder" type="url" class="defaultTextBox advancedSearchTextBox link" placeholder="http://www.youtube.com">
    <input class="btn" type="submit">Go</input>
</form>
```

You might also need an `if` statement in main.py that actually renders the page

```py
  @app.route('/button', methods=["GET", "POST"])
  def button():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html")
    if request.method == "POST":
      dlink = request.form.get("linkHolder")
      print(dlink)
      return render_template("index.html", dlink=dlink)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a form with the name
Also, your tag `</input>` input doesn't have any closing tag you should be using button tag

```html
<form method="POST" action="/button">
    <input type="text" name="linkHolder">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```